# Менять пароль пользователя в ходе выполнения скрипта

Tags: c, users, freebsd

Доброго времени суток, у меня стоит интересная задачка в ходе корой мне необходимо менять пароль пользователя в ходе выполнения скрипта. Из всего что я знаю о фряхе я остановился на команде passwd, но так как она получает пароль только при вводе, пытался вызвать ее через popen и в поток забить новый пасс, но увы ничего не удалось...
P.S. по факту мне нужно создать пользователя, но команда pw не принимает пароль, насколько я понял. и связи с этим приходится искать решение выше указанного геморроя

Comment: Там через псевдотерминал (pty) надо работать.  

В принципе не очень сложно написать некий 2-направленный аналог popen() на псевдотерминале вместо pipe.

Например, expect делает так в spawn.

Comment: а можно чуть подробнее??? по фряхе я еще зелель сочная....

Comment: Изучайте. [Например, можно почитать здесь](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Low_002dLevel-Terminal-Interface.html#Low_002dLevel-Terminal-Interface).

Или покороче [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476354/how-do-nix-pseudo-terminals-work-whats-the-master-slave-channel).

Идея в том, что Вы делаете псевдотерминал (это как бы связка из двух устройств -- master и slave (ведет себя аналогично обычному tty)), делаете fork и там dup дескрипторов 0,1,2 на slave, после exec passwd она считает что работает с терминалом.

Родительский процесс обменивается байтиками по master.

Comment: @Sayori, думаю, [man 3 forkpty](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=forkpty&category=3&russian=1) это то, что Вам нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, [man 3 forkpty](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=forkpty&category=3&russian=1) это то, что Вам нужно.

Там через псевдотерминал (*pty*) надо работать. В принципе, не очень сложно написать некий двунаправленный аналог `popen()` на псевдотерминале вместо *pipe*. Например, *expect* делает так в *spawn*.

Например, можно почитать [здесь](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Low_002dLevel-Terminal-Interface.html#Low_002dLevel-Terminal-Interface). Или покороче [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476354/how-do-nix-pseudo-terminals-work-whats-the-master-slave-channel). Идея в том, что Вы делаете псевдотерминал (это как бы связка из двух устройств -- *master* и *slave* (ведет себя аналогично обычному *tty*)), делаете *fork* и там *dup* дескрипторов `0,1,2` на *slave*, после *exec passwd* она считает, что работает с терминалом. Родительский процесс обменивается байтиками по *master*.

---

ответ составлен из комментариев, написанных [avp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/232) к вопросу.

Comment: А [здесь, уже не ru.SO](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428999/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B-bash-%D1%81-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F) пример передачи пароля для su.

Comment: @avp, там из `shell-а`, тут из `c`. мне кажется, есть разница.

Comment: Там название вопроса не соответствует его сути. Автору надо вызывать su из Qt (вот я и привел пример на Си, как это делать).

Comment: @avp, тогда, возможно, имеет смысл назначить тот вопрос дублем этого? правда, не знаю, насколько это оправданно — там, вроде, речь про gnu/linux, здесь про freebsd.

Comment: Не думаю, и дело тут не столько в метках (мне кажется, большая часть посетителей о них вообще не думает), сколько в складывающейся порочной практике редактирования реальности. Все должно идти само собой, может слегка подталкиваемое (прокомментировать или пройти мимо) в нужном направлении.