# Выполнение команды bash с автоподстановкой пароля

Tags: qt, bash, авторизация

Задача: запуск из основной программы на Qt 4, которая запускается под любым обычным пользователем, графического приложения под рутом. Нельзя использовать sudo, expect.

В общем случае необходимо выполнить команду `su -c "запуск программы"` с автоподстановкой пароля. Т.е. `echo "пароль" | su -c "запуск программы"` Как обойти ошибку "su должен запускать из терминала"?
В итоге должна запуститься искомая программа под su, с автоподстановкой пароля.

При использовании QProcess требует запуск через терминал. 
Поэтому сейчас пытаюсь выполнить su через псевдотерминал. 
Застрял на проблеме подстановки пароля, т.е. эмуляции ввода пользователем (если я правильно понимаю, стандартный stdin не поможет, т.к. пароль для su читается напрямую из tty и не может быть введен никак, кроме как вручную)

Comment: для подобного лучше использовать *sudo* без пароля (с ограничением на запускаемую программу, конечно).

Comment: sudo не подходит)

Comment: да, так часто случается: наиболее подходящее средство отвергается по (обычно) необъктивным причинам.

Comment: может человек шеллкод пишет и два байта - очень приципиально.

Comment: Да, для su (и ssh) нужен терминал (псевдотерминал, *pty*). / Посмотрите в сторону [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin sudo не подходит, к сожалению, т.к. основная программа (в которой этот запуск происходит) должна работать для любого обычного пользователя, без добавления его в sudoers и прочих предварительных операций. аналогично gksu, fly-su, kdesu, pkexec и т.д. Т.е. нужно именно su с подстановкой пароля.

Comment: Господа, речь об этом: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/427907/ @Emm, укажите в вопросе свои задачи явно, а то так и будем ходить по кругу.

Comment: Теперь понятно. Автор, все же на чем саму запускалку писать думаете Си (С++) или bash? (отвечайте с упоминанием @nick, а то иначе тут сейчас нотификации не будет).

Comment: @avp сама программа на Си++ (qt4). С процессами на Qt не вышло, сейчас пробую через псевдотерминал (forkpty)

Comment: Да, мне тоже кажется проще всего запустить su -l USER -c ... под pty и пусть она сама разбирается с авторизацией.

Comment: @avp теперь стоит задача, как эмулировать ввод пароля пользователем в псевдотерминале)

Comment: Сначала прочтите приглашение 'Password: ', от su, потом write() пароль. Потом  надо определить, что все OK.

Comment: @avp огромное спасибо, все получилось.

Comment: @Emm, а опобликуйте здесь же свое решение (ответьте сами на вопрос), а я напишу свой. Думаю такой код может оказаться полезным (ранее на ХК уже были подобные вопросы).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отлично, что у Вас получилось. Думаю, что использование forkpty и пример вызова su может оказаться интересным достаточно многим программистам на C/C++.

Поэтому рискнул привести небольшой код.

```
// avp 2015 link with -lutil

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <pty.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <limits.h>

// returns master pty fd or -1 on error
int
pty_execvp (char *argv[], pid_t *child)
{
  int master;

  if (!(*child = forkpty(&master, 0, 0, 0))) {
    execvp(argv[0], argv);
    /*
      Вот это незадача...
      Здесь мы в child process, а stderr и stdout (да и управляющий /dev/tty)
      уже перенаправлены на master.
      Ни о каких log-файлах нам неизвестно, так что похоже ничего не остается,
      как отправить error message вызвавшей нас функции через master.
      Ведь все равно она должна быть готова к обработке сообщений об ошибках
      в программе argv[0].
     */
    err(EX_UNAVAILABLE, "PID %ld exec %s", (long)getpid(), argv[0]);
    // NOT REACHABLE
  } else if (*child == -1) {
    warn("PID %ld forkpty %s", (long)getpid, argv[0]);
    return -1;
  }

  struct termios t;
  tcgetattr(master, &t);
  cfmakeraw(&t);
  tcsetattr(master, TCSAFLUSH, &t);

  return master;
}

/*
  Run su -l USER -c COMMAND in child process 
  Returns pty (COMMAND's stdin, stdout, stderr) as FILE * (or NULL on error)
 */
FILE *
run_su (const char *cmd, const char *user, const char *passwd, pid_t *child)
{
  /*
    Возможно эту функцию стоит дополнить установкой таймаута...
    (особенно если ее модифицировать для запуска scp/ssh)
   */
  char *ecmd, 
    /*
      Для упрощения нашей задачи по определению успешности запуска /bin/su
      добавим к выводу CMD "уникальную" строку, которую сформируем в ok_reply[].
      Для этого вместо "su -c CMD" запустим "su -c echo OK_REPLY; CMD"
      и если первая прочитанная от su строка (после передачи пароля)
      не равна ожидаемой, то будем считать, что это ошибка аутентификации.
     */
    ok_reply[20], buf[LINE_MAX];

  char *su[] = {
    (char *)"/bin/su",
    (char *)"-l",
    (char *)user,
    (char *)"-c",
    0, //"echo xaxa ; ls -l /tmp", 
    0
  };
  FILE *pty;
  int bsize = sizeof(buf) - 1, l, master;


  sprintf(ok_reply, "OK %ld", (long)getpid());
  if (asprintf(&ecmd, "echo %s; %s", ok_reply, cmd) < 0) {
    perror("run_su() asprintf");
    return 0;
  }
  su[4] = ecmd;

  master = pty_execvp(su, child);
  free(ecmd);
  if (master < 0)
    return 0;

  /*
    Теоретически эти 10 байт (слово "Password: ")
    надо бы читать порциями  в цикле и с таймаутом, 
    проверяя не закрыл ли child свой tty
   */
  if ((l = read(master, buf, bsize)) < 0) {
    perror("run_su() read Password: ");
    goto Err;
  }
  buf[l] = 0;
  if (strncmp("Password: ", buf, 10)) {
    fputs("Unexpected su message:  ", stderr);
    fputs(buf, stderr);
    goto Err;
  }

  if (write(master, passwd, strlen(passwd)) < 0 ||
      write(master, "\n", 1) < 0 ||
      read(master, buf, 1) < 0) {
    perror("run_su() handshake su error");
    goto Err;
  }

  if (!(pty = fdopen(master, "r+"))) {
    perror("fun_su() fdopen pty");
  Err:;
    close(master);
    return 0;
  }
  if (!fgets(buf, bsize, pty) || strncmp(ok_reply, buf, strlen(ok_reply))) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Auth failure. Message: %s\n", buf);
    fclose(pty);
    return 0;
  }

  return pty;
}



int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  pid_t child;
  FILE *pty = run_su("ls -al /tmp", "testuser", "toor", &child);
  int c;

  puts("Gooo");
  while (pty && (c = fgetc(pty)) != EOF)
    putchar(c);

  if (wait(&c) != child)
    err(1, "unexpected child");
  if (WIFEXITED(c))
    printf("result: %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(c));
  else
    printf("terminated %d\n", WTERMSIG(c));

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Comment: @Emm, улучшил обработку ошибок и добавил комментарии к коду

Answer (score 1):

Может быть надо просто скрипту поставить SUID bit? В этом случае он будет выполняться от имени владельца, коим может быть кто угодно, хоть root.

Мысль, что программа "должна работать для любого обычного пользователя, без добавления его в sudoers и прочих предварительных операций" противоречит всем принципам безопасности. Либо она доступна всем пользователям и тогда su ей не нужно, либо кто-то, имеющий права root разрешает ее исполнение - правит sudo или устанавливает ей SUID bit.

Comment: Вы уверены, что `s` бит для root  в Linux для скриптов (bash и т.п.) работает? Можете продемонстрировать???

Comment: @avp так работает pkexec, у него установлен suid бит и владелец root

Comment: @Emm, так это же **не скрипт!!!** / `file /usr/bin/pkexec / ...
/usr/bin/pkexec: setuid ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386,.....`

Comment: Да. Действительно. Был неправ. Правильно будет все-таки использовать sudo.

Answer (score 0):

```
"echo \"пароль\" | sudo -S -запуск программы"
```

но это плохая затея:)

Comment: если выполнять непосредственно в консоли, с su ту же ошибку выдает ( su: должен запускаться из терминала ), с sudo  тоже ругается, что неправильные параметры.

Comment: потестил и поправил. Вот так echo "test" | sudo -S '/usr/bin/cat /proc/meminfo' не работает. а вот без кавычек - работает echo "test" | sudo -S /usr/bin/cat /proc/meminfo

Comment: @ KoVadim sudo не подходит, к сожалению, т.к. основная программа (в которой этот запуск происходит) должна работать для любого обычного пользователя, без добавления его в sudoers и прочих предварительных операций. аналогично gksu, fly-su, kdesu, pkexec и т.д. Т.е. нужно именно su с подстановкой пароля.

Comment: Так вы исходники-то посмотрели? Хоть gksu, хоть fly-su, неважно. Там же всё работает.

Comment: @Emm а зачем нужен этот запуск? может Вы решаете банальную задачу неведомыми науке способами?

Comment: @KoVadim, см. в комментах к главпосту.

Answer (score -1):

Используйте expect в linux. Построчно сможете описать все действия.

Comment: expect использовать нежелательно, т.к. требует установки